# Jquery UI last clicked tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, lazy-loading, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a few tabs with images. The idea is to show images only from the clicked tab, something like this:

`$("#tabs").tabs({ 
            show: function(event, ui) {

                $('img.lazy', ui.panel).each(function(){ 
                    var imageSrc = $(this).attr("data-original-src"); 
                $(this).attr("src", imageSrc); 
            }); 
        } 
    });`

But some tabs have almost 750 images. How can I stop dowload images from old tab if new tab is clicked? I think it should be something like this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
 show: function(event, ui) {
     if (oldui != null) {
         $('img.lazy', oldui.panel).each(function() { 
             $(this).attr("src", "");
         });
     }
     oldui = ui;
     $('img.lazy', ui.panel).each(function() {
         var imageSrc = $(this).attr("data-original-src");
         $(this).attr("src", imageSrc);
     });
 }
```

});

but how can I get last clicked tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ui.index is the current one, store this in variable on show method:

```
var prevTab = 0;
$("#tabs").tabs({
 show: function(event, ui) {
     if(prevTab != ui.index) {
       //do it here....
     }
     prevTab = ui.index; 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we can get access to old panel with `ui.oldPanel`
    `$("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $('img.lazy', ui.oldPanel).each(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/card-text-bg.png");
        });
        $('img.lazy', ui.panel).each(function () {
            var imageSrc = $(this).attr("data-original");
            $(this).attr("src", imageSrc);
        });
    }
});`